# Python Requests getting TypeError when attempting to POST with Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm trying to do a form login on a page and I keep getting the below type error. I have read the [Python Requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) documentation and when I print my data dictionary it looks like a valid example. I'm not sure what is going wrong. Here is my code with Traceback:

```
import requests

accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
acceptlang = "en-US,en;q=0.9"
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
userid = 'username'
passwd = 'password'

headers = {
        'Accept': accept,
        'Accept-Language': acceptlang,
    }

data = {userid: fakeuserid, passwd: fakepasswd}

>>> print(data)
{'username': 'fakeuser@example.com', 'password': '0#CCJyy3^5Tu(Z'}
>>> response = requests.post(url, headers, data=data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: post() got multiple values for argument 'data'
```

When I POST with either only (url, headers) or (url, data=data) the post succeeds. I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [requests API](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/), it looks as if you need the keyword for your `headers` argument, without which *post()* assumes it's `data`. Try this:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some API servers only accept JSON-Encoded POST/PATCH data, do like this:

```
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

It just the same as:

```
import json
response = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

See more at: [docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: Please add a description of your code so we know what it does and why.